# App Is Not Responsive Due To Variable Size

Tags: android

So I am writing a data science application which collects data from several sensors and sends them to drop box.

My app is hanging whenever data in `sensorReading` is more than say `500 kB` and my stop button fails to work promptly.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_pos_poll_side: {

                if (LightSensor != null || mProximity != null || mAccelerometer != null || mGyroscope != null) {

                    mySensorManager.registerListener(
                            MultiSensorListener,
                            LightSensor,
                            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

                    mySensorManager.registerListener(
                            MultiSensorListener,
                            mProximity,
                            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

                    mySensorManager.registerListener(
                            MultiSensorListener,
                            mAccelerometer,
                            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

                    mySensorManager.registerListener(
                            MultiSensorListener,
                            mGyroscope,
                            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

                    //print output text
                    side_output.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h3> ----- Data Collection Session Starts Here -----</h3>"));

                } else {
                    side_output.setText("No Sensor Found!");
                }
                break;
            }

            case R.id.btn_stop_poll_side: {
                mySensorManager.unregisterListener(MultiSensorListener,
                        LightSensor);
                mySensorManager.unregisterListener(MultiSensorListener,
                        mProximity);
                mySensorManager.unregisterListener(MultiSensorListener,
                        mAccelerometer);
                mySensorManager.unregisterListener(MultiSensorListener,
                        mGyroscope);
                side_output.append("\n" + sensorReading);
                /*
                    Reading data and writing to Dropbox!
                 */
                new DropboxTask(side_output, "Back Pocket Data Reading", sensorReading).execute();
                break;
            }            
        }
    }

    private final SensorEventListener MultiSensorListener
            = new SensorEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {

                numLightSensor = event.values[0];
                sensorReading += "\"BackPocket\" " + String.valueOf(numLightSensor) + " " +
                        String.valueOf(numProximitySensor) + " " +
                        String.valueOf(numAccelerometer_X) + " " +
                        String.valueOf(numAccelerometer_Y) + " " +
                        String.valueOf(numAccelerometer_Z) + " " +
                        String.valueOf(numGyroscope_X) + " " +
                        String.valueOf(numGyroscope_Y) + " " +
                        String.valueOf(numGyroscope_Z) + "\n";
            }
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {

                //similar as above
            }
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

               //similar as above
            }

            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {

                //similar as above
            }
        }
    };
```

How can I make it work optimally?
Thanks!

Comment: Something tells me you're doing this on the main thread, and you're choking the memory out essentially. Android is not multithreaded by default, so you might want to try doing the recording on a Worker thread instead.

Comment: @KoltenSturgill You are correct. Any ideas how to implement this in a different thread? My lack of android experience lead me to a few failed tries.

Comment: From the docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html, you were on the right track with the Handler and Runnable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not try and implement it, now I will.

Comment: No problem! Good luck, this looks pretty cool.